# Edit existing value of attribute based on value in another attribute within the same node in XML with R

Tags: r, xml, xml2

I have the following XML that I would like to parse. The repeated attribute names are making it difficult to get the output I would like.

It seems an obvious solution to this problem is to alter the values of the attribute score.

```
      <linescore score="129">
        <quarter quarter="1" score="16"/>
        <quarter quarter="2" score="30"/>
        <quarter quarter="3" score="42"/>
        <quarter quarter="4" score="27"/>
        <quarter quarter="5" score="9"/>
        <quarter quarter="6" score="5"/>
```

How do you go about changing the value of score based on the value of quarter? For example:

```
      <linescore score="129">
        <quarter quarter="1" score="16_1"/>
        <quarter quarter="2" score="30_2"/>
        <quarter quarter="3" score="42_3"/>
        <quarter quarter="4" score="27_4"/>
        <quarter quarter="5" score="9_5"/>
        <quarter quarter="6" score="5_6"/>
```

I've tried using `xml_replace` but have not been successful.

Comment: Show attempted code. Show full XML (especially headers). Show current undesired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
library(xml2)
library(purrr)
xml <- read_xml('
<linescore score="129">
<quarter quarter="1" score="16"/>
<quarter quarter="2" score="30"/>
<quarter quarter="3" score="42"/>
<quarter quarter="4" score="27"/>
<quarter quarter="5" score="9"/>
<quarter quarter="6" score="5"/>
</linescore>')
xml %>% 
  xml_find_all("/linescore/quarter") %>% 
  walk(~xml_set_attr(.x, "score", paste(xml_attrs(.x)[c("score", "quarter")], collapse ="_"))) 
xml  
# xml_document}
# <linescore score="129">
# [1] <quarter quarter="1" score="16_1"/>
# [2] <quarter quarter="2" score="30_2"/>
# [3] <quarter quarter="3" score="42_3"/>
# [4] <quarter quarter="4" score="27_4"/>
# [5] <quarter quarter="5" score="9_5"/>
# [6] <quarter quarter="6" score="5_6"/>
```